# "come off hot down home" means

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "Did he say anything to you?" Garraty asked.
>
> "He asked me if it was commencing to ***come off hot down home***," Baker said shyly. "Yeah, he . . . the Major talked to me."
>
> "Not as hot as it's gonna commence getting up here." Olson cracked.

I don't get what the phrase means. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

> The major asked Baker if the weather was beginning to be hot down South where he is from. They are in Maine at the start of the Long Walk, i.e. in the North of the US. The question was asked to Baker (by the Major) who is from Louisiana, i.e. "down South" from where they are. [Source](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305637/what-does-it-mean-by-it-comes-off-hot-down-home)

Baker is not actually using what we call "standard english" and is therefore tricky to understand.

Comment: ok. What about ""Not as hot as it's gonna commence getting up here."? What's Olson saying?

Comment: Its obviously a joke, but I am not sure due to insufficient context given, do you have an online copy of this by any chance? (I am assuming Olson means that they are "getting" somewhere of where they are standing is getting hot)

Comment: The other question you linked me in seems to have a link to thr source.

Comment: That's a wikipedia page @dan